# Oracle password has expired, however I have no way of changing it

Tags: oracle

When I connect to my local development database, I get an error saying the password has expired.  I've been trying to change it with `sqlplus` to no avail:

```
C:\>sqlplus TPMDBO/password@localhost/global

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Wed Nov 6 15:41:02 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-28001: the password has expired


Changing password for TPMDBO
New password:
Retype new password:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Password unchanged
```

I get this error no matter what *new password* I type in.

My main question is how I can reset this password.  However, I'm also curious if there's a way to make the password never expire.  This is a local dev database, I really don't care about the security or anything and none of the data on it is important.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the account is locked, as far as I know, the user can't change it. The Oracle output in your question shows the account is not *locked*, but *expired*.

Log in to your database as a user who has privilege to alter other users (for example, `SYS`) and issue the following command:

```
ALTER USER tmpdbo IDENTIFIED BY new_password;
```

You can change the expiration behaviour. There already was a question about that on Stack Overflow:

[Make Oracle Password Never Expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095871/how-do-i-turn-off-oracle-password-expiration)

Comment: Do you mean that 1. If the account is locked, the user can't change it. And 2. If  the account is not locked, but expired, the user can't change it, too. And whatever happen, the user need other user who has privilege to alter other users to change password again?

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party here but I just ran into this and at least in my case I am fairly certain it is an oracle bug, possibly with compatibility between client versions. I was getting this error connecting to an 11g database using the 12g sql*plus client while another person was able to successfully log in and change the password using the 11g sql*plus client. They always say things are backwards compatible. They aren't always right...

Answer (score 0):

Many of my coworkers, including myself, have been having this issue last four years (yes, that long). We have discovered that those of us who have this issue are NOT set as (Windows) Admin on our own machines. 
On the other hand, those coworkers whose machines (and therefore the very same version of SQLPlus program we have) we use to reset our PROD passwords ARE set as (Windows) Admin on their own machines.

Answer (score -4):

log into sqlplus as username:SYSTEM
give previous password

```
sql>password
old_password:<oldpassword>
new_password:<new password>
retype new password:<new password>
password is set
```

Comment: This changes the password for  the user SYSTEM, not the user "TPMDBO".